# Problem with JSON result arriving with recordset

Tags: node.js, json, express

I made a simple api that connects to sql server with nodejs. My JSON is duplicated and comes with recordsets syntax. Even though I used all `JSON.stringify()` methods to change this, there was no change.

```
request.query('select ID as id,DISPLAY_MESSAGE_1 as description from pos  where ID=20524', function (err, recordset) {
            
if (err) console.log(err)

res.send(recordset);
```

result;

```
{"recordsets":[[{"id":"20524","description":"MERHABA"}]],"recordset":[{"id":"20524","description":"MERHABA"}],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[1]}
```

The result I expect is as follows:

```
{
  "id": 20524,
  "description": "MERHABA"
}
```

Comment: It's Javascript, you can get the subarray of the recordset object and return the parts you want

Comment: Is your question relevant to SQL Server i.e. are you wanting a SQL solution? If not please remove the tag.

Comment: Not sure why this is surprising, that's the documented structure expected in the callback. Perhaps your confusion stems from using a callback signature with misnamed variables, i.e.: `function (err, recordset)` instead of the documented `function (err, result)`? The `result` is expected to have an array-of-arrays property `recordsets` (plural) and an array property `recordset` (singular) that is equivalent to `recordsets[0]`. Given your current callback have you tried simply using `res.send(recordset.recordset)` instead? Ref: [mssql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes thank you. I tried for hours, but I couldn't think of using `res.send(recordset.recordset)` This solved the problem I was having.